# Adobe PDF - Dynamically setting a subject when submitting form

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I want to pull data from my adobe form to put in the subject - but I think I'm running into an issue because I'm trying to put javascript vars in what's supposed to be HTML code.

```
var todaysdate = this.getField("DWH").value;
var foreman = this.getField("Foreman").value;

this.mailDoc({
bUI: false,
cTo: "test@testing.com",
cSubject: "New Daily from "+ foreman + " " + todaysdate",
cMsg: "placeholder text"
});
```

I need this to be sent as an entire PDF, not FDF.  I looked up the API references for Adobe Javascript, and couldn't find any help there regarding putting PDF Form data in.

Currently, this gives me an unterminated string literal on the subject line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the string is not terminated in the cSubject line… count the quote characters; the number should be even, but is odd.

Removing the quote character just before the comma at the end will make the code work.